# how to fix "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Panic! This is a bug!" in dataflow`s pipeline

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, grpc

How to fix the follwing error in dataflow`s pipeline?

> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Panic! This is a bug!

This is a exception form the line options.getService();
I have set the stackdriver logging api to On;

I setup the service account's permission to owner.

```java
LoggingOptions options = LoggingOptions.getDefaultInstance();
try (Logging logging = options.getService()) {

    LogEntry entry = LogEntry.newBuilder(JsonPayload.of(map))
        .setSeverity(Severity.INFO)
        .setLogName("xxx-log")
        .setResource(MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global").build())
        .build();

    logging.setWriteSynchronicity(Synchronicity.SYNC);
    logging.write(Collections.singleton(entry));
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Here is my dependency and version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.56.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your project ID and Dataflow job id is needed to investigate this kind of issue and you do not (and should not) want to expose your project . Please file the issue using this link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187168&template=0

Comment: i resolved the problem.

Comment: can you answer with how you resolved it?

Comment: in the pom,there is a lot of comfict. about the gcp`s version, i modify that with the same version.